# what is the regex expression to have `first as numeric value with comma and then the string with the space (e.g - 20,000 value)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

what is the regex expression to have `first as numeric value with comma and then the string with the space (e.g - 20,000 value) ?

I have come up with the following regex . `[\d,\svalue]` but the problem here is , once any one of the single character is matched. it passes. i want all the conditions to be met and then it should pass. e.g - first it should start with the number. The number value could have comma and then the string value with the space.

Comment: Your example does not match your expectations. `20,000` has no space.

Comment: @tadman but ‘20,000 value’ in his example does :)

Comment: @BenjaminJamesKippax I was so thrown off by the `-` being shown but in the example that I didn't even realize literal "value" was part of it.

Comment: When giving examples of literal text, try and use the backticks tag. *e.g. - 20,000 value* leaves a lot of ambiguity. `20,000 value` does not. I interpreted the former as *e.g. `- 20,000` value*.

Comment: @tadman understandable, I had to re-read a couple of times to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

(([0-9]{1,},[0-9]{1,}){1,}\svalue)

1 or more numbers, followed by a comma, followed by 1 or more numbers, followed by a space, followed by the string ‘value’

Wrapping the entire pattern in () creates a group.

[image]

Comment: @steve this was the shortest pattern I could get personally.

Comment: @steve you’re very welcome. Don’t forget to mark the response as an answer for other users to see too.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very pretty, but something like this should work..

```regex
(?=.)(\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*)(\.\d+)?(\s[a-zA-Z]+)?
```

You can view the query [here](https://regex101.com/r/rWEUoR/2)

[image]